# css child max-depth selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a descendant selector for css that restrict the depth that it applies to?

I imagine it would be something like `div span:(max-depth:2)`

```
<div>
    <span> <!-- depth 1 -->
        <span> <!-- depth 2 -->
            <span> <!-- depth 3 -->
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

In this example, it would match the first two spans but not the third.

It would be nice if we had something that scaled well when there is a *lot* of nesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can combine the immediate child rule to reach that level

```
div > span,
div > span > span{ 

}
```

or even

```
div > *,
div > * > * {

}
```

to catch two levels deep of anything in a `div`

Answer (score 0):

@iPherian, the possibilities are endless. But unfortunately, these answers are as close to your wanted, but unfortunately, non-existent, <s>`div span:(max-depth:2)`</s>.

```css
.one {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.two {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.three {
  height: 90px;
  background-color: violet;
}

#firstDiv > .one span {
  background-color: lightgreen!important;
}

#secondDiv > .one * {
  background-color: lightgreen!important;
}

#thirdDiv span span {
  background-color: lightgreen!important;
}

#fourthDiv span > * {
  background-color: lightgreen!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="originalDiv">
  <span class="one"> <!-- depth 1 -->
    Hello
    <span class="two"> <!-- depth 2 -->
      Hai
      <span class="three"> <!-- depth 3 -->
        Hi
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>

<div id="firstDiv">
  <span class="one"> <!-- depth 1 -->
    Hello
    <span class="two"> <!-- depth 2 -->
      Hai
      <span class="three"> <!-- depth 3 -->
        Hi
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>

<div id="secondDiv">
  <span class="one"> <!-- depth 1 -->
    Hello
    <span class="two"> <!-- depth 2 -->
      Hai
      <span class="three"> <!-- depth 3 -->
        Hi
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>

<div id="thirdDiv">
  <span class="one"> <!-- depth 1 -->
    Hello
    <span class="two"> <!-- depth 2 -->
      Hai
      <span class="three"> <!-- depth 3 -->
        Hi
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>

<div id="fourthDiv">
  <span class="one"> <!-- depth 1 -->
    Hello
    <span class="two"> <!-- depth 2 -->
      Hai
      <span class="three"> <!-- depth 3 -->
        Hi
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I changed the example many times and didn't realize I used the ids multiple times. It is fixed now!